# string and integer sum calculate in php?

Tags: php, string, sum, numbers

```
<?php
    $a = '32abc';
    $b = 1;
    echo $a + $b;

    Output : 33
?>
```

Here string `$a = '32abc';` calculate with int `$b = 1`, how take 32 from string word in php. and output show 33 . is there any good explanation on it?

Comment: Do you look for explanation of this behavior?  Look this: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-php-mysql/9781449337452/ch04s05.html

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.numeric-strings.php . Since PHP 7.1, this will have raised a notice about a "non well-formed numeric value". PHP 8 increased this to a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Try operator `intval` for extract int from string.
But work only if int in the start of string.

```
    $a = intval('32abc');
    $b = 1;
    echo $a + $b;
```

Comment: `intval()` has nothing to do with extracting numbers from a string, the behavior you're seeing is defined [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.numeric-strings.php).

Answer (score 0):

Try preg_replace to allow only numbers, so like this:

```
<?php

$a = '32abc'; 
$b = 'abc1';
$c = '1abc1';
$d = 6;

echo preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '',   $a) + preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '',   $b) + preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '',   $c) + $d;

?>
```

will echo 50 (32 + 1 + 11 + 6)

You could also make a function and do it like:

```
echo removeCharsFromString($a) + removeCharsFromString($b) + removeCharsFromString($c) + $d;

function removeCharsFromString(string $inputString) {
    return (int) preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '',   $inputString);
}
```